# What is the best practice to use BottomNavigationView after SplashFragment when Navigation Component is usedin Android

Tags: android, android-fragments, mobile, android-activity

I'm developing a new Android application and I want to use Single-Activity-Multiple-View architecture. I have to show a splash fragment and when the user is directed to the next page, there should be a BottomNavigationView and a couple of Fragments. As it is recommended to add BottomNavigationView inside an activity, not a fragment! What is the solution not to change Splash**Fragment** to Splash**Activity** and adhere to Single-Activity-Multiple-View architecture?